# accessing $resource instance url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I created resource instance with this code:

```
$scope.book = Book.get({bookId:1});
```

Here is service code:

```
var bookServices=angular.module('bookServices',['ngResource']);

bookServices.factory('Book',['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('/books/:bookId',{},{});
    }]);
```

Book has cover image, accessible by url:
/books/:bookId/cover.png

How can I get url from resource instance?

```
$scope.book.$$url
```

is undefined.

Comment: If you just want the URL to the book's cover page image, you can formulate it using the book's ID: `var coverPageUrl = '/books/' + $scope.book.id + '/cover.png'`;

Comment: it is solution, but I need to repeat resource URL, used in resource construction. I think there must be more beautiful way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a view concern and should be handled there.  I can't test this now, but my hunch would be to build the url in your view template.

So, the book detail template would be:

```
<div>
     <p>Name: {{ book.name }}</p>         
     <img ng-src="/books/{{ book.id }}/cover.png" alt="cover">
</div>
```

You might need to play with the relative path, but that should do the trick.  You want to keep these concerns out out your controller and services, and angular comes with plenty of tools, like the [ngSrc directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc), to do just that.

**EDIT**

Perhaps to better answer the original question, here's another solution.  Use the decorator pattern to *extend* the $resource service api to expose the url as a property of a resource object.

Decorate the $resource service like this:

```
function ResourceDecorator($delegate) {

  var decorator = function (url, paramDefaults, actions) {

    var resource = $delegate(url, paramDefaults, actions),
        getSave;

    // expose the parameterized url of the resource
    resource.$url = url;

    // expose urls for individual resources by extending
    // the get method to return a class object that has
    // a url property

    getSave = resource.get;

    resource.get = function(parameters, success, error) {

      var r = getSave(parameters, success, error),
              paramName;

      // get the name of the parameter, assuming just ONE            
      paramName = Object.keys(parameters)[0];

      // replace the parameter with it's value
      r.$url = url.replace(':' + paramName, parameters[paramName]);

      // return the decorated class object back
      return r;
    };

    return resource;

  };

  return decorator;

}

app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('$resource', ['$delegate', ResourceDecorator]);

}]);
```

Then you will have the url available as a property on your resource object.

```
$scope.book.$url
```

Note that there's a whole wack of $resource scenarios that this simple example doesn't support, but it shows a proof of concept.

See [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/apsQQXXlUbHcm1iDaP6Q) plunker.

Comment: I think the green flag is totally misleading. This answer is a workaround and has nothing to do with what was asked in the title.

Comment: Agreed. I have the same problem and this is not a real solution.

Comment: I would have checked the url for ':' before getting keys and replacing parameters